# Slow lint with prettier

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, eslint, prettier-eslint

Created a new React project. There is almost nothing there -- just SSR, code splitting and a couple of 'hello world!' pages. On top of eslint added prettier. Before I added prettier the lint used to take 10-15 sec. Now I got +2mins for almost empty project:

```
time yarn lint
yarn lint  3.19s user 0.49s system 2% cpu 2:35.39 total
```

Thought that I'm linting node_modules. In order to check that updated 2 files:

```
// node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js
...
create(context) {
    const sourceCode = context.getSourceCode();
    // ########### LOG #############
    console.log(`eslint processing file [${+new Date()}] ${context.getFilename()}`);

    const REST_PROPERTY_TYPE = /^(?:RestElement|(?:Experimental)?RestProperty)$/u;
```

and

```
// node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier.js
...
        const prettierFileInfo = prettier.getFileInfo.sync(
          filepath,
          Object.assign(
            {},
            { resolveConfig: true, ignorePath: '.prettierignore' },
            eslintFileInfoOptions
          )
        );
        // ############## LOG ########################
        console.log('Prettier processing file', filepath);

        // Skip if file is ignored using a .prettierignore file
        if (prettierFileInfo.ignored) {
```

Would really appreciate it if you could tell me a better way to list processed files. A trick with

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "lint": " DEBUG=eslint:* eslint --ext .js --fix server src tools",
```

gave too much data.

Not sure do I even need this file

```
# .prettierignore
# Ignore everything:
/*

# Good guys
!/src
!/server
!/tools
```

The output showed me that difference between timestamps of the first and the last file is ~1.5 sec.

```
  eslint processing file [1592686834050] /Users/...
  Prettier processing file...
  ....
  eslint processing file [1592686835724] /Users/...
  Prettier processing file ...
```

Just wondering, what for are used the rest of 1500 sec?

.eslintrc file

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
  ],
  "env": {
    "browser" : true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "prettier",
    "react-hooks",
    "jsdoc",
    "jest"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "max-len": [2, 120],
    "react/jsx-wrap-multilines": ["error", {"declaration": false, "assignment": false}],
    "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
    "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "curly": ["error", "all"],
    "jsdoc/check-indentation": "error",
    "jsdoc/check-param-names": "error",
    "jsdoc/check-property-names": "error",
    "jsdoc/check-tag-names": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-hyphen-before-param-description": ["error", "never"],
    "jsdoc/require-param-description": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-param-name": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-param-type": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-param": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-property": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-property-name": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-property-type": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-returns-description": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-returns-type": "error",
    "jsdoc/require-returns": "error"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src", "server", "tools"]
      }
    }
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": [ "**/*.stories.js", "**/*.story.js" ],
      "rules": {
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarted Mac and got a normal processing time (~4 secs):

```
time yarn lint
yarn lint  4.09s user 0.61s system 109% cpu 4.279 total
```